# Hide/Disable edit button on select UITABLEVIEW cells?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITABLEVIEW where I want to show the delete function for only certain cells (that is, certain cells are user deletable certain cells aren't).  As far as I can tell, seteditable: is only set at the table level.  Is there a way to override this or hide the delete button on certain cells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should implement

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in tableview delegate. There you can return appropriate editing style for your cells: *UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete* for deletable cells, *UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone* for others